# How do you format this join? Nesting and project ID errors

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

so I have been trying my best to pull this data for so long and I can't for the life of me figure it out. I am trying to do the following:

```
Join my table (`x-1269.WorkingData.lease_approved_3_month`) as
(a) with the (`x-1269.94317304.ga_sessions_*`) as (GA) data on  
FullvistorID (both have this ID under the same name)
```

And I want to see the following items on the table

```
a.date,
a.device, 
a.fullVisitorId, 
a.visitId, 
a.MessageGUId,
a.Status, 
a.LeadStatus, 
a.LeadDate, 
a.UpdatedDateTime,
GA.hits.eventInfo.eventCategory, 
GA.hits.eventInfo.eventAction,
GA.hits.eventInfo.eventLabel 
Where   Event category = request tour and Event action = submit
```

I have tinkered with it a lot and have spliced other codes into it to try to get it to work but nada.

I even tried a more simple version but it lead to nesting problems:

```
Select 
•   a.date,
•   a.device,
•   a.fullVisitorId,
•   a.visitId,
•   a.MessageGUId,
•   a.Status,
•   a.LeadStatus,
•   a.LeadDate,
•   a.UpdatedDateTime,
•   GA.hits.eventInfo.eventCategory,
•   GA.hits.eventInfo.eventAction,
•   GA.hits.eventInfo.eventLabel
From `x-1269.WorkingData.lease_approved_3_month` as a
Left join `x-1269.94317304.ga_sessions_*` GA on GA.fullVisitorId = a.fullVisitorId
where 
`GA.hits.eventInfo.eventCategory` = request_tour and `GA.hits.eventInfo.eventAction` = submit
Unest (hits) as hits
```

And here is my current iteration of it but it has "Invalid project ID 'GA.hits'.":

```
    with vars as
        (
           select ('20210801') as startdate,
              ('20220801') as enddate
        )
    , allsitesdata as -- pull all the GA for this site in the specified date range
    (
           select 'Site.com' as site,
              GA.*,
           from   `x-1269.94317304.ga_sessions_*` GA,
              vars 
           join `x-1269.WorkingData.lease_approved_3_month` as a on GA.fullVisitorId = a.fullVisitorId
           where  _table_suffix between startdate and enddate #apts
    ), hitlevel as
    (select hits.eventInfo.eventCategory, hits.eventInfo.eventAction, hits.eventInfo.eventLabel from allsitesdata cross join unnest(hits) as hits)
    select * from hitlevel,b.fullVisitorID,
    a.date,
    a.device,
    a.fullVisitorId,
    a.visitId,
    a.MessageGUId,
    a.Status,
    a.LeadStatus,
    a.LeadDate,
    a.UpdatedDateTime,
    GA.hits.eventInfo.eventCategory,
    GA.hits.eventInfo.eventAction,
    GA.hits.eventInfo.eventLabel
    where 
    `GA.hits.eventInfo.eventCategory` = request_tour and `GA.hits.eventInfo.eventAction` = submit
```

Comment: Can you share the structure of `lease_approved_3_month` and `ga_sessions_*` ?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out had to move the unnesting thing:

```
Select 
a.device,
a.fullVisitorId,
a.visitId,
a.MessageGUId,
a.Status,
a.LeadStatus,
a.LeadDate,
a.UpdatedDateTime,
hits.eventInfo.eventCategory,
hits.eventInfo.eventAction,
hits.eventInfo.eventLabel
From `x-1269.WorkingData.lease_approved_3_month` as a
Left join `x-1269.94317304.ga_sessions_*` GA on GA.fullVisitorId = a.fullVisitorId, unnest (hits) as hits
where 
hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'request_tour' and hits.eventInfo.eventAction = 'submit'
limit 10
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).